# Substances in Unity 2018.1

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to import substance to my project in Unity 2018.1. I have downloaded the "Substances in Unity" by allegorithmic from the asset store. Then i import substance to my project and i cannot use it. I get this error:

> Assets/Materials/metallic_car_paint.sbsar: Built-in support for Substance Designer materials has been removed from Unity. To continue using Substance Designer materials, you will need to install Allegorithmic's external importer from the Asset Store.

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEkTx9AAV2E) in 5:00 he is downloading the file and he can open and unfold the Substance. My problem is that when i unfold the main substance in inspector looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a video that mentions updating it from the package manager instead: https://youtu.be/9j2b8zqlTzA?t=1m21s

If that still doesn't work then just delete all files associated with the plugin and re-import it.